# When not to use Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

In the Hadoop Definitive Guide it's said that Pig Latin doesn't suit for all data processing task. But It only cites "to perform queries of small amount of data in a large set" as a example.

Which other examples are bad scenarios of use for Pig Latin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be situations when you just have simple ad-hoc analytical queries into the data in HDFS. There Hive would be more useful as Hive queries are a lot faster to write for those types of queries.

Also you may refer this post [Pig vs Hive vs Native Map Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950248/pig-vs-hive-vs-native-map-reduce)!.